# R, find the exact word from a vector, create index, then apply the index to query in a different column

Tags: r, indexing, filter

I have a ID vector.

| ID |
| --- |
| A1 |
| B3 |
| C2 |
| D1 |

I have a `df` that includes ID and Value.

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A1; A2; A3; A4 | 1; 2; 3; 4 |
| B1; B2; B3 | 4; 5; 6 |
| C1; C2 | 7; 8 |
| D1 | 9 |

Now I would like create R function to map the IDs from ID vector to ID in the `df`, then extract the ith value from Value column. The expected output column would be like this.

| Value |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 6 |
| 8 |
| 9 |

Would you be able to give any suggestion to create a R function?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please share your data by entering `dput(df)` in R and pasting the result into your question? The structure of your data isn't clear. eg, is `ID` a character column, or a list column?

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I just re-posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71506999/r-find-pattern-and-create-index-then-filter-another-column-based-on-the-create.

Comment: thank you, and glad you got an answer to your question. In the future, it’s better to just edit your original post than to create a new one.