# R, find pattern and create index, then filter another column based on the created index

Tags: r, indexing, filter

I have a value df `df1 = data.frame(ID = c("A1; A2; A3; A4", "B1; B2; B3", "C1; C2","D1"), Value = c("1; 2; 3; 4", "5; 6; 7", "8; 9", "10"))`.

I have another df `df2 = data.frame(ID = c("A2", "B3", "C2", "D1"))`.

Now I would like to write a function to map the 'ID' from df2 to 'ID' in df1, then filter the Value based on the ith position of ID column. The expected output is `filtered_df1 = data.frame(ID=c("A2", "B3", "C2", "D1"), value = c("2", "7", "9", "10"))`.

Would you be able to give any suggestion to create R function?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `separate_rows` function from `tidyr` package combined with `right_join` to get numeric for Value add `type.convert(as.is = TRUE)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  separate_rows(c(ID, Value)) %>% 
  right_join(df2) %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

```
  ID    Value
  <chr> <int>
1 A2        2
2 B3        7
3 C2        9
4 D1       10
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird structure to encounter in the wild, it is inadvisable to store key-value pairs this way. First, fixing `df1` to be humanly usable.

```
library(tidyverse)
f <- function(x, y) {
  x %>%
    separate_rows(ID, Value, sep = "; ") %>%
    right_join(y, by = "ID") %>%
    mutate(Value = as.numeric(Value))
}

f(df1, df2)
  ID    Value
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A2        2
2 B3        7
3 C2        9
4 D1       10
```

Answer (score 0):

**data.table**

```r
df1 = data.frame(
  ID = c("A1; A2; A3; A4", "B1; B2; B3", "C1; C2", "D1"),
  Value = c("1; 2; 3; 4", "5; 6; 7", "8; 9", "10")
)

df2 = data.frame(ID = c("A2", "B3", "C2", "D1"))

filtered_df1 = data.frame(ID = c("A2", "B3", "C2", "D1"),
                          value = c("2", "7", "9", "10"))


library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

COLS <- c("ID", "Value")
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) unlist(tstrsplit(x, split = "; ")))] %>%
  merge(y = df2, all.y = TRUE) %>%
  .[, lapply(.SD, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)]

#>    ID Value
#> 1: A2     2
#> 2: B3     7
#> 3: C2     9
#> 4: D1    10
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>